# C# - Log custom exceptions with NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I am trying to configure NLog to log my own exceptions and system exceptions into 2 different log files.
Let's say when I run `_logger.LogError("This is my exception.")`, it should be logged to `myerrors.log`, but when the server crashes, the error should be logged to a different file.
The problem I have now is that, the system errors are logged into both files.
This is my `nlog.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile=".\SystemLogs\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName=".\SystemLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName=".\ErrorLogs\${shortdate}\errors-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Here is the appsettings.json config:

```
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
```

Comment: What will you see in your logs when the server crashes? An error or fatal? In your nlog configuration rules you specify the minimum log level and that’s why it logs on both

Comment: Is this the correct config? I don't see a `myerrors.log`

Comment: @Julian `myerrors.log` is a placeholder, in the config its `errors-${shortdate}.log`

Comment: Maybe print ${logger} for "but when the server crashes". I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to configure a Global Exception handling mechanism which would handle any unhandled exception.

In .Net Core, you can do that by creating a middleware refer [link](https://blog.elmah.io/error-logging-middleware-in-aspnetcore/).

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> _logger;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        ApiResponse<object> response = new ApiResponse<object>(exception, EResponseCode.GlobalException, exception.Message, null);

        string responseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(responseString);
    }
}
```

Then, register it in `Startup.cs` by `app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();`

**Create a target named globalErrors.**

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="globalErrors" fileName="\globalErrors.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

Configure logs coming from the middleware.

```
<logger name="*.ExceptionMiddleware" writeTo="globalErrors" />
```